# Android UI Testing(Espresso): How to get all elements within a ListView with Espresso?

Tags: android, listview, automated-tests, ui-automation, android-espresso

Let's say I have a ListView like the one shown in the picture below:

I want to write a UI test using Android Espresso and get ALL the visible elements within that list. After that I want to randomly click some row in the ListView and determine every one of them that was clicked and get the text from them. Is that possible? As I see, the Espresso documentation regarding ListView testing is pretty poor.
[image]